# Why the little group of a massless spin-1 particle is $ISO(2)$ rather than $SO(2)$?

Tags: momentum, group-theory, representation-theory, invariants, poincare-symmetry

As the title suggests, after going through a lot of Wikipedia, and references of books, I have learned that: The little group of a massive spin-1 particle is $SO(3)$, while the little group of a massless spin-1 particle is $ISO(2)$ or $E(2)$, as far as the unitary representation of Poincare group is concerned.

My question is: Why the little group of a massless spin-1 particle is $ISO(2)$ rather than $SO(2)$? I don't really see how the translations of the 2-dimensional Euclidean group play a role here (for example, take the momentum to be $p^\mu=(E,0,0,E)$ with polarizations $\epsilon_1=(0,1,0,0)$ and $\epsilon_2=(0,0,1,0)$. Or I can similarly ask why the little group of a massive spin-1 particle is $SO(3)$ rather than $ISO(3)$.

Comment: You need to work with the full symmetry group to ensure your equations that emerge (in this case Maxwell’s equations) possess all the relevant symmetries. As an aside, have you read Wigner’s original article on the matter? He explains this quite clearly IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a brief explanation: In the 3+1D massless case we can assume that the only non-zero component of the momentum $P_{\mu}$ is the [lightcone coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-cone_coordinates) $P_+$. Besides the homogeneous $O(2)$ group [of reflections and rotations in the transverse $12$-plane generated by the angular momentum $M_{12}$] such momentum also commute with the Lorentz generators $M_{-i}$ with index $i\neq \pm$, which make up the inhomogeneous part of [$E(2)=ISO(2)\cong O(2) \ltimes \mathbb{R}^{2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group). (It would have been more logical to name it $IO(2)$, but unfortunately this is not recognized.)

Comment: Thanks, your explanation works! I have also found an explicit explanation in Weinberg's first volume, page 70.