The little group of the connected Lorentz group
For $n\geq 2$, the $n$-dimensional  connected Lorentz group is defined as $$SO(n-1,1)^{\uparrow}=\{f\in M_n (\mathbb{R}):f^T\eta f=\eta, \det (f)=1,f^0_0>0\}$$ where $$\eta=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0&  \cdots & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Assume that $p=(E,E,0,\ldots ,0)$. I would appreciate if someone could help me  about proving this fact: The little group of $p$ under $SO(n-1,1)^{\uparrow}$ is $SO(n-2)\ltimes \mathbb{R}^{n-2}$, the Euclidean group. I mean,   $$SO(n-1,1)^{\uparrow}_p =\{ fp=p:f\in SO(n-1,1)^{\uparrow}\}.$$

What is $\nu$, it seems to me as though it should be an $n\times n$ matrix if it is being multiplied by an $n\times n$ matrix on both sides.

Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/578059/2451

The massless little group is $ISO(n-2)$, not $SO(n-2)$. You are trying to prove something that is not true.
